# is it possible to purge topic when kafka broker is down

Tags: apache-kafka, purge

We have 3 kafka machines, and we want to purge all the topics in the kafka

**as the following**

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper master:2181 --alter --topic Topic_Name --config retention.ms=1000
```

the problem is that two of the kafka machines have a problem that kafka broker on kafka01/03 restarting all the time , or kafka broker is down on kadka01/03

***so my question is: can we purge Topics on the good machine - kafka02 in spite kafka01/03 broker is down ?***

second - how to verify success after purge topic ?

Comment: have you tried to delete data folders on all boxes?

Comment: Please stop tagging Hadoop for Kafka questions. They are unrelated

Comment: I not want to delete the topics , we want to purge the topics without to delete the folders